# Use numpy in python3 - Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to use `numpy` with `python3` in Ubuntu 12.04. The command `python3` in the terminal returns:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 20:13:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
```

When I try to import `numpy` I get the error:

```
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

So I tried to install it with:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

which returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

So it is installed but for python2.7 and apparently I need to install `numpy` for python3. If I do:

```
sudo pip install upgrade
```

I get:

```
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement upgrade
No distributions at all found for upgrade
```

I've tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096143/why-doesnt-numpy-import-in-idle-3-30-on-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit?rq=1), namely doing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

which is not found. I've also gone [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.7.1) but I only see Windows versions available for download for python3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to install it from Ubuntu repositories, which is easier, but the version is older, try

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

If you want it via `pip`, you should probably start with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

and then you'll have something like `easy_install-3.2` which you can use to

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

and then

```
sudo pip-3.2 install numpy
```

Comment: Well that was simple. Thank you! Since I saw in several places people recommending the use of `pip` when installing python dependencies I thought I should use it too.

Comment: @Gabriel `pip` will get you the latest version, but it will also build the package locally, so you need to have all build dependencies installed. Sometimes it can get tedious with packages like `numpy` or `matplotlib`.

Comment: I tried to follow your second way but after the last command I get a `pip-3.2` command not found error.

Comment: @Gabriel Type `pip` and hit the Tab key for auto-completion, there must be an executable with a similar name, maybe `pip3`. But if you already installed `numpy` from Ubuntu reps, I don't recommend installing another version with `pip`.

Comment: `pip3` does not exist in my system and the auto-completion gives me 164 possibilities only one of them being `.pip/`. In any case, your first solution worked so I better move on with installing `matplotlib` to work with `python3` which is not simple apparently. Cheers.

Comment: I'm having alot of similar issues -- I can't get (any) packages to run in Python3 / Spyder3, I've tried everything with path and interpreter, multiple installs.  I don't know what to do here.  I have Spyder2.6 that runs with pandas, but I need ib_insync, which doesn't work with 2.6, shows I have it installed, but will not run in either.